# Timer-related void call bugs out entire program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.timers.timer

Okay so here is the important bit of the code:

```
public bool open = false;

//CODE FOR CALLING VOID "EverySecond"
var DT = new System.Timers.Timer();     //Yes i am using System.Timers
DT.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(EverySecond);
DT.Interval = 1000;
/*
    SOME CODE CHANGING SOME UNIMPORTANT TEXTBOXES
*/
DT.Start();

private void EverySecond(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (pb1.Value < 100)
        pb1.Value += 1;
    sl -= 1;
    tbTime.Text = "Estimated " + sl.ToString() + " seconds left";
    if (pb1.Value >= 100)
        pb1.Value = 100;
    if (pb1.Value == 100 && open == false)
    {
        Form frm6 = new frm6();
        frm6.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

So basically everytime i run this all the code runs fine, but then i come to this piece of code (if (pb1.Value == 100 && open == false)) and the entire program freezes and outputs 1 Form a second (which is logical due to the current configuration of the script) BUT i have tried it a million different ways and it does somewhat the same, it just shows me the hourglass cursor and all the buttons and textboxes are misplaced and the progressbar disappears, and it's just a mess.

Comment: what is s1 and pb1? IF you are using these variables from main class and you don't have any thread safety or locking mechanism. you can expect lots of mess :) what if EverySecond is called before the other one finishes

Comment: Why are you calling `this.Close()`? - don't you mean `frm6.Close()`? - how would the closuere of the `this` class affect the timer?

Comment: And what's in the constructor, iniitlizer and form load methods in `frm6`?

Comment: First of all: What is that _supposed to_ do? Then, does `pb1.Value` get set from somewhere else, too? When and by what is `open` set? And last but not least: Pretty sure, you shouldn't set `tbTime.Text` from that context.

Comment: If the timer instance keeps the Form from actually closing, the timer will keep on firing and the condition will stay true... so maybe start by switching off the timer and disposing it.

Comment: since i work in WinForms in Visual Studio, the pb1 is a progress bar (not the thing crashing the program as it works), "sl" is an integer that is displaying amount of seconds left until it finished (it is hardcoded to finish with a calculated delay between them).

Comment: Without a [mcve], impossible to give a good answer. But: only `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` operates on the correct thread for GUI objects. If you are creating/showing a form in the wrong thread, it won't work. It's also not clear why, given that you never stop the timer, you are surprised that it repeatedly attempts to create and show a new instance of the form. Please improve the question.

Comment: Again, `tbTime`, `pb1`: You shouldn't set properties of UI Components from a non-UI Thread. But that's not the main culprit here, I think. Calling `this.Close()` from non-UI Thread I think is.

Comment: okay so to Fildor the thing about the timer doing it before stopping, i fixed that but still the same problem with the forms and hourglass and stuff.

Comment: The easiest change you can make is using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, so you don't need to have headaches about marshalling. It will make sure you are on the correct thread. Then you should already see a different error, if any.

Comment: and to whoever said that i shouldn't change textboxes etc. in the same thread, this is a "GUI prototype" kinda program (need it done as fast as possible, just that the UI and timing works basically) and i have set properties of UI from similar (if not the same) kind of threads before and it has worked fine, so don't think that is the thing

Comment: yes i tried using the Forms.Timer but i can't call a void from that (using the Timer.Elapsed thing) is there a way to call a void once a second with a regular Forms.Timer? if so i think that might fix the problem

Comment: _"so don't think that is the thing"_ - The thing about that is: It _may_ even work sometimes. But it _will_ come around to bite you in the buttocks.

Comment: Instead of `Elapsed` event you simply register for the [`Tick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick?view=netcore-3.1) event on a WinForms Timer.

Comment: okay so i changed the timers and i changed the Elapsed to Tick but how do i do the "ElapsedEventHandler" with a regular timer?

Comment: Try telling us what you're actually trying to do. For example "I would like to show a progress bar form that crawls from 0 to 100 % over the course of one minute and then closes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, you need to use a regular Forms.Timer instead, and replace "Timer.Elapsed" with "Timer.Tick" and removed "Elapsed" from "ElapsedEventHandler" and "ElapsedEventArgs" Like this:

```
public bool open = false;

//CODE FOR CALLING VOID "EverySecond"
Timer DT = new Timer();
DT.Tick += new EventHandler(EverySecond);
DT.Interval = 1000;
/*
    SOME CODE CHANGING SOME UNIMPORTANT TEXTBOXES
*/
DT.Start();

private void EverySecond(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pb1.Value < 100)
        pb1.Value += 1;
    sl -= 1;
    tbTime.Text = "Estimated " + sl.ToString() + " seconds left";
    if (pb1.Value >= 100)
        pb1.Value = 100;
    if (pb1.Value == 100 && open == false)
    {
        Form frm6 = new frm6();
        frm6.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```